# Parallelism in Golub & van Loan's Jacobi algorithm for symmetric eigenvalue problems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

In Matrix Computations by Golub and Van Loan (3rd edition, page 433) an algorithm is given for a parallel version of the classical Jacobi algorithm for solving a real symmetric eigenvalue problem. The algorithm overwrites the real symmetric matrix $A$ with $V^TAV$ where $V$ is orthogonal.

The idea is that each set of 2-by-2 symmetric Schur decompositions are non-conflicting and therefore can be done in parallel. From p. 432:

> Note that all the rotations within each of the three rotation sets are "non-conflicting". That is, subproblems (1, 2) and (3, 4) can be carried out in parallel.

However, I cannot see how this is the case. Clearly I am missing something (or the book is wrong). Here is the point of confusion:

Within the inner loop, we have the update step:
$$ A = J(p, q, \theta)^TAJ(p, q, \theta). $$

This modifies both rows $p$ and $q$ and columns $p$ and $q$ of matrix $A$. Therefore for two subproblems $(p, q)$ in a set such as $\{(1, 2), (3, 4)\}$, the updates are conflicting because, for example, element $A(1, 3)$ is modified by both sets.

Could anyone please explain what I am missing in order to correctly implement this parallel algorithm?

EDIT: Here is the pseudocode. (Sorry I couldn't get the indentations right.) The subroutine 'music' just rotates the set of indices in 'top' and 'bottom' to generate new pairs of indices that are "non-conflicting". If you can see how this would work in the first iteration, i.e. set=1, that would be sufficient.

> Algorithm 8.4.4 (Parallel Order Jacobi)
> Given a symmetric $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ and a tolerance $tol > 0$, this algorithm overwrites $A$ with $V^TAV$ where $V$ is orthogonal and off$(V^TAV) \leq tol \|A\|_F$. It is assumed that $n$ is even.
>
> $V = I_n$
> $eps = tol \|A\|_F$
> $top = 1:2:n; bot = 2:2:n$
> **while** off$(A) > eps$
> **for** $set=1:n-1$
> **for** $k = 1 : n/2$
> $p = min(top(k), bot(k))$
> $q = max(top(k), bot(k))$
> $(c, s) = $**sym.schur2**$(A, p, q)$
> $A = J(p, q, \theta)^T A J(p, q, \theta)$
> $V = VJ(p, q, \theta)$
> **end**
> $[top, bot] = $**music**$(top, bot, n)$
> **end**
> **end**

The text below states:

> Notice that the $k$-loop steps through $n/2$ independent, nonconflicting sub-problems.

Comment: Perhaps they mean that the updates could be applied in any order, which is true. However, this is not quite the same as being able to perform them in parallel on a shared $A$ matrix.

Comment: Could you post the parallel algorithm (or its core steps)? Maybe  they do something clever?

Comment: I updated the question to include the pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the $2x2$ Schur-decompositions are non-conflicting and can be done in parallel. The update of $A$ however is indeed conflicting.

Comment: It is hard to see then how this constitutes a parallel algorithm.